# ExecuteSqlCommand possible to access table in another context?

Tags: sql, sql-server, .net-core

I've built a query that involves joining 2 tables that exist in separate databases. I'd like to run this query within my .NET Core 2.1 application. Here is what I've got:

Query:

```
INSERT INTO Database2.dbo.Table2
SELECT * FROM Table1
    WHERE Col1 = 5
```

This query works just fine within SQL Operations studio.

C#:

```
using(var context = ConnectionHelper.getContext(dbInfo))
{
    string MySQLQuery = 
        " INSERT INTO Database2.dbo.Table2 " +
        " SELECT * FROM Table1 " +
        "     WHERE Col1 = 5 ";
    try 
    {
        context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(MySQLQuery);
    } 
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message); // This doesn't get called, the query doesn't throw an error.
    }
}
```

When I run the query through .NET Core, nothing happens. I expect ~1000 rows to be written to `Database2.dbo.Table2`, but 0 are written. No Error message is logged, so .NET Core seems to think it succeeded in performing the given SQL query. I'm assuming the error is being caused by my reference to `Database2`.

Comment: I've done some .NET work, but not core. Does this require your connection to be open? I don't see that in the code. When you debug, does your try block even get executed?

Comment: @JacobH This is proper syntax - We have many other queries being ran this way that work perfectly, they just don't attempt to reference tables outside of their context.

Comment: Maybe try with the USE statement instead of the multi-part identifier? Or maybe flip the database so you're doing an INSERT locally while reading from the other database.

Comment: But then `Table1` exists in another database @JacobH that wouldn't help.

Comment: can you try printing out "SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE Col1 = 5"

Comment: @NevilleNazerane Don't know why you want this, but it returns 1423 rows. I said in the OP that the SQL itself if functional.

Comment: I'll say up front, I'm not entirely familiar with the environment you're working with, but does it make a difference to explicitly reference `Database1.dbo.Table1` in the query?  Could the query be attempting to `SELECT` from a non-existent `Database2.dbo.Table1`?  Or even making an explicit reference to `Table1.Col1` could make a difference.

Comment: @Steve-o169 it does not make a difference. I believe the error is being caused by the way EF manages the scope of executed SQL queries.

Comment: i believe that ef core dos not do such cross database actions. maybe if you add a synonym on the first db and call it like that? i do know exactly. Workaround can be achieved by not using a query rather leveraging object in app layer but that is not that good for such action as it will create a lot of db traffic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to the problem was to avoid using `ExecuteSqlCommand` within a given context. Since I didn't specifically need any features of EF for this query, I ended up using `SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()` from the `System.Data.SqlClient` library. Here's a working example:

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(< your connection string >))
{
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
    command.CommandText = " SQL STATEMENT HERE ";
    command.Connection = con;
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```